# HTML Layout: mixing [Element] and [Signal Element] in an Elm web apge

Tags: html, layout, elm

I am reading about `flow down` and it's suppose to let us stack elements vertically on our web site.  What are you supposed to do when when parts of your website are signals? I would picture a web site like this:

- Introduction
- Dynamic Component
- More Static Text

The type of `flow down: [Element] -> Element` so I can't just mix in `[signal Element]` as I would like.  In a previous solution I saw solutions involving `lift` so here's what I came up with:

```
import Random
main = column <~ (constant "5") ~ (Random.range 0 100 (every second))
column x y = flow down [asText x, asText y]
```

Here I just stack the number 5 on top of a randomly changing number.  Perhaps it depends depends on the Window size,

```
import Random
import Window

main = column <~ (constant "5") ~ Window.dimensions
column x y = flow down [asText x, asText y]
```

Is this considered good practice or are there better ways of doing layout in Elm?

Answer (score 2):

Extracting a non-signal function and lifting it is generally good practice. In this case you could also use [`Signal.Extra.combine : [Signal a] -> Signal [a]`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Apanatshka/elm-signal-extra/5.6.0/Signal-Extra#combine) if you like:

```
main = flow down <~ combine [constant (asText "5"), asText <~ Window.dimensions]
```

As you can see, there is a lot more lifting going on than in your solution, just to get it into a one-liner. So I don't think it's ideal. But `combine` can be handy in other (more dynamic) situations.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of the library function that I linked to.

Comment: has combine been dropped since?

Comment: @SimonH yes, it was deemed too infrequently used. So I defined it in my signal utility library. I updated the post to link to that library now.

Answer (score 1):

Up to date answer.
Either you use combine, which is now in the Signal-extra library or, for this simple case

```
 column x y = 
    Signal.map (flow down) <|
      Signal.map2 (\a b -> [a, b]) (show x) (show y)
```